# query elasticsearch can get a document by id but not find it in query all

Tags: elasticsearch

I was using ES 2.3, now I am upgrade it to ES 7.4. The data was generated through auto test.So it will always be 32 documents.

I found when I was using ES 2.3 with query all, I got all 32 documents.
The document, for example, `data.id: 5dba917f61b48a327c948557` can be found in the result.
And I can query it by `data.id`, the documents can be found as well.

But if I do the same thing using ES 7, I `CAN NOT` find the document with `data.id:5dba917f61b48a327c948557`
in query all eg. http://localhost:9200/test-auditing-2019-10/_search?pretty=true results.

```
{
  "took" : 16,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 32,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test-auditing-2019-10",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "J0LIIG4Bw-26hPm9OiXO",
...
```

I do get the documents when query http://localhost:9200/test-auditing-2019-10/_search?q=data.id:5dba917f61b48a327c948557&pretty=true .

```
...
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 2.3795462,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test-auditing-2019-10",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "RELIIG4Bw-26hPm9WyUP",
...
```

What is wrong? Is this expected? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ElasticSearch 2.3 is too old, maybe it would return all matched documents. I don't have this version, and cannot reproduce it.

However, modern ElasticSearch only returns 10 matched documents by default, even if your query matches all documents. In order to get more matched documents, you can use the `from` and `size` to do pagination:

Get first 32 documents:

```
http://localhost:9200/test-auditing-2019-10/_search?from=0&size=32&pretty=true
```

Get the next 32 documents:

```
http://localhost:9200/test-auditing-2019-10/_search?from=32&size=32&pretty=true
```